# Help me solve this diophantine equation- $x^5+x^4+1=7^y$

Tags: number-theory

An obvious soloution is $(x,y) = (2,2)$, but I can't figure out which module should I look for to show there are no more solutions...

Comment: If there are solutions in $\mathbb{N}$, then there are solutions modulo $m$ for every positive integer $m$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all positive integer solutions of the equation $n^5+n^4 = 7^m-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258070/find-all-positive-integer-solutions-of-the-equation-n5n4-7m-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2B1%3D7%5Ey%24&p=1).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yeah, that seems to be it. Thanks!